# Update collection of a related entity with the newly created/deleted object (onFlush)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following setup of Doctrine entities:

```
class MainEntity
{
    /**
     * @var SecondEntity[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SecondEntity", mappedBy="mainEntity", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $secondEntities;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="second_entities_count")
     */
    private $secondEntitiesCount;

    ...
}

class SecondEntity
{
    /**
     * @var MainEntity
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MainEntity", inversedBy="secondEntities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $mainEntity;

    ...
}
```

When a `SecondEntity` is created or deleted, I want the `$secondEntitiesCount` in the related `MainEntity` to be updated accordingly.

To achieve this, I have created an `onFlush` subscriber that gathers all scheduled deletions and insertions of `SecondEntity` objects

```
$delsertions = array_merge(
    $unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityInsertions(),
    $unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityDeletions()
);
foreach ($delsertions as $entity) {
    if ($entity instanceof SecondEntity) {
        $mainEntity = $entity->getMainEntity();

        $mainEntityMeta = $em->getClassMetadata(MainEntity::class);
        $unitOfWork->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($mainEntityMeta, $mainEntity);

        dump($mainEntity->getSecondEntities); // The creation/deletion of the current entity is not reflected here!
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the `dump()` above, the collection has not been updated accordingly after the creation/deletion of the entity that triggered the subscriber. For example, if I'm creating the first `SecondEntity` for a given `MainEntity`, the `$secondEntities` collection will be empty.
And if I'm deleting the only `SecondEntity`, the `$secondEntities` collection would still have that object inside it.
The `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet()` call doesn't seem to do anything in this case.

How can I force the collection to be properly updated?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class UpdateMainListener
{
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        // only act on "SecondEntity" entity
        if (!$entity instanceof SecondEntity) {
            return;
        }

        $main = $entity->getMainEntity();
        if(!is_null($main))
            $main->increaseSecondEntitiesCount();
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        // only act on "SecondEntity" entity
        if (!$entity instanceof SecondEntity) {
            return;
        }

        $main = $entity->getMainEntity();
        if(!is_null($main))
            $main->decreaseSecondEntitiesCount();
    }
}
```

and then set services:

```
mybundle.prepersist.listener:
    class: MyBundle\EventListener\UpdateMainListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
mybundle.preremove.listener:
    class: MyBundle\EventListener\UpdateMainListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preRemove }
```